# Issue laying out components with React and Flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

Here is a puzzling problem I am facing with the layout of some components in a web app.

First of all here is the source code *MyCompo.js*:

```
import React from "react";
import tblClp from './images/WoodSquare.jpg';
import dwnArwClp from './images/DownArrow.png';
import upArwClp from './images/UpArrow.png';
import './MyCompo.css';

class MyCompo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const elements = [...Array(3).keys()]
    const items = []
    
    for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
      items.push(<SquareUnit index={index}/>)
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SquareUnit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div id={this.props.index}>
                    <div><img src={tblClp} width='130' height='109'/>
            <div className="overlay down">
                <img src={dwnArwClp} width='40' height='40'/>
                </div>
            <div className="overlay up">
                <img src={upArwClp} width='40' height='40'/>
              </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default MyCompo;
```

And here is the style sheet *MyCompo.css*:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.overlay {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: .3s ease;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.down {
    top: -24%;
    left: 3%;
}

.up {
    top: -76%;
    left: 65%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

I run my app for development using this command in the terminal:

```
$ npm start
```

And this is what I see in the browser after adjusting the *.down {...}* and *.up {...}* blocks inside *MyCompo.css* and saving the file.

[image]

As one can see *MyCompo* is made of three wooden square blocks, each one having two arrows (up and down) overlayed on top of it.

The above screenshot is what I get as well as what I expect.

But here comes the problem and my question:

When I refresh the browser window, the display changes to the following:

[image]

which is no longer what I expect.

What is wrong in my code *MyCompo.js* or *MyCompo.css* for this to happen?

Comment: Have you considered placing the square wooden blocks in the `backgroud-image` of the `<div>`, instead of leaving it in a sibling `<img/>` element of the arrows?

Comment: No I hadn't thought about it, but I am looking into this now.

Comment: After some time spent trying out several options, I now have something working based on using a backgroud-image of a <div>.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `.container` class is never implemented on the parent div, so it does not have the `display: relative` applied to it, forcing the arrows outside of it. My guess is that this should fix it:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <div id={this.props.index}>
        <div className="container">
            <img src={tblClp} width='130' height='109'/>
            <div className="overlay down">
                <img src={dwnArwClp} width='40' height='40'/>
            </div>
            <div className="overlay up">
                <img src={upArwClp} width='40' height='40'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now solved, below is how I did.

First of all here is the new source code MyCompo.js:

```
    import React from "react";
    import dwnArwClp from './images/DownArrow.png';
    import upArwClp from './images/UpArrow.png';
    import './MyCompo.css';

    class MyCompo extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const elements = [...Array(3).keys()]
        
        const items = []
        
        for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
          items.push(<SquareUnit index={index}/>)
        }
        
        return (
          <div>
            {items}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    class SquareUnit extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div id={this.props.index} className='tblBlk'>
                        <div className='tblCell'>
                <div className="overlay down">
                    <img src={dwnArwClp} width='40' height='40'/>
                  </div>
                <div className="overlay up">
                    <img src={upArwClp} width='40' height='40'/>
                  </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }
    }

    export default MyCompo;
```

And here is the new style sheet MyCompo.css:

```
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .sqBlk {
        padding-top: 11px;
        padding-bottom: 11px;
    }
    
    .sqCell {
        background-image: url("./images/WoodSquare.jpg");
        width: 130px;
        height: 109px;
    }
    
    .overlay {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.4;
        transition: .3s ease;
        background-color: transparent;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    .down {
        top: 60%;
        left: 4%;
    }
    
    .up {
        top: -96%;
        left: 65%;
    }
```